# Swift 2.0 UIScrollView как ограничить прокрутку по frame

Tags: swift

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Имеется UIScrollView с горизонтальной прокруткой с загрузкой изображений из массива (работает) - как сделать прокрутку только по frame изображений; сейчас прокрутка работает из любой части экрана

---

import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    /************* scroll index ***************/        

    let korobkaImages = korobka //  имя массива 
    let imageWidth:CGFloat = 75 // размер изображения
    let imageHeight:CGFloat = 75

    let yPosition:CGFloat = 500 // для варианта по вертикали или позиция по У
    var xPosition: CGFloat = 20
    var scrollViewContentSize:CGFloat=0;
    for var index=0; index<korobka.count; index++

    {
        let UIEdgeInsetsZero: UIEdgeInsets

        let korobkaScrollView = scrollView // назначение ...
        let korobkaImage: UIImage = UIImage(named: korobkaImages[index])!
        let korobkaImageView: UIImageView = UIImageView()
        korobkaImageView.image = korobkaImage
        korobkaImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
        korobkaImageView.frame.size.width = imageWidth
        korobkaImageView.frame.size.height = imageHeight
        korobkaImageView.center = self.view.center            
        korobkaImageView.frame.origin.x = xPosition // для варианта по горизонтали
        korobkaImageView.frame.origin.y = yPosition // для варианта по вертикали и дает положение У
        korobkaScrollView.addSubview(korobkaImageView)
        let spacer:CGFloat = 10
        xPosition+=imageWidth + spacer // для варианта по горизонтали
        // yPosition+=imageHeight + spacer // для варианта по вертикали

        scrollViewContentSize += imageWidth + spacer // для варианта по горизонтали
        // scrollViewContentSize += imageHeight + spacer // для варианта по вертикали

         korobkaScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollViewContentSize, height: imageHeight) // для варианта по горизонтали
        // myScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: imageWidth, height: scrollViewContentSize) // для варианта по вертикали

    }  //скобка закрытия for


    //var contentInset: UIEdgeInsets  // default UIEdgeInsetsZero. add additional scroll area around content
```

после запуска прокрутку можно делать по горизонтали (курсором) из любой точки экрана - нужно по полосе загруженных изображений в нижней части экрана
по фрейму линейки изображения...приблизительно

Comment: вот это не совсем понятно было

Comment: поправил с кодами...а как работает эта штука = идет через почту или как-то только через сайт  @Max Mikheyenko

Comment: что именно идет через сайт//почту?

Comment: вот эта штука @Max Mikheyenko

Comment: комментарии? у меня например уведомление на телефон приходит. какими еще способами уведомления рассылаются не знаю

Comment: ладно, вопрос то в чем? вам надо чтобы скроллвью двигался только если касание произошло на одной из картинок, и не просто внутри фрейма скроллвью?

Comment: в принципе по этому вопросу здесь = Swift_2.0 Как применить UIPanGestureRecogniser к image в UIScrollView - нужно движение внутри фрейма скролвью и затем выбранный объект двинуть по вертикали на фрейм другого имажа...без вставки в скрол без массива  вроде как смоделировал по UISwipeGestureRecognizer а в данном варианте - затык...не нравится,что из любой точки экрана можно скролить... @Max Mikheyenko

Comment: короче вам надо, чтобы после того как произошло касание на картинке, при движении пальцем, она начинала двигаться по экрану без привязки к скроллвью?

Comment: 1-scrollView находится внизу экрана (только в портрете) - по всей ширине экрана ,frame скрола высотой 100px - в скрол из массива грузятся изображения 100 х 100 которые можно прокручивать по горизонтали...но прокрутка почему-то возможна не только в границах frame скрола , но и из любой точки экрана = как сделать чтобы прокрутка была только в границах frame скрола, а не из любого места экрана -2 - выбранный по центру Х в скроле имаже нужно переместить UP в границы другого имаже ... @Max Mikheyenko

Comment: ладно, в этом месте я отчался понять что надо. может кто другой разберется.

Comment: бывает...@Max Mikheyenko

Comment: Можете хоть скрины с пояснениями добавить?

Comment: прокрутка содержимого UIScrollView осуществляется по горизонтали...причем  касание возможно в любом месте экрана, а не только в кадре UIScrollView...нужно чтобы касание действовало только в пределах кадра UIScrollView = ? @VAndrJ